# Group column in csv file by pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have data

```
ID,"day"
00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401,2016-03-01
00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401,2016-03-06
000700651343ff73c10212a095ab4091,2016-03-06
000700651343ff73c10212a095ab4091,2016-03-01
00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d,2016-03-01
```

I try to print to every data list of unique users

```
df = pd.read_csv("users.csv")
df = df.groupby('day')['ID'].unique().reset_index(name="unique")
users = df["unique"]
for elem in users:
    print elem
```

and get

```
['00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401' ..., '00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d']
['00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401' ..., '000700651343ff73c10212a095ab4091']
```

They not delimited with `,` and there are not all values, instead this in contain `...`. How can I change that and get lists?

Comment: They are numpy arrays, why do you want lists?

Comment: @AndyHayden I want intersect this with lists from other table, but with other table I get lists. But when I intersect lists from two columns I get empty value, because this is not lists

Comment: You probably want `set`s for intersection. Try `df.groupby('day').agg(lambda s: set(s))`.

Comment: Perhaps you could do this entire operation more efficiently with a [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). *At the moment this is an example of [The XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/184179).*

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko, but I should intersect this with column from other `excel`. When I do some actions with that `excel` I get data like this format `[u'b2b5b93270cb217310b0719946b0afee', u'71f464119a2d43834c3be0af362487bc', u'afad5e5f9c3ba9df885eba1557ab7c73', u'eef9d076cdc3bfcb282047f1792a5971']`

Answer (score 0):

Those are numpy arrays, and the `...` is just because the list is long and numpy has a feature where it doesn't show you every element if the list is too long. The elements are there.

If you want a list you can just use `list(elem)`